# java string Constant : hex value for a single character - how?

Tags: java, string, hex

I need to replicate a character in a unix file, that looks like this:

```
cat myfile | xxd -ps | sed 's/[[:xdigit:]]\{2\}/\\x&/g'
```

result -> `... \xa4 ...`

How can I put this character, which looks like hex `A4` into a String literal in java?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
public final static String SEPARATOR = "\ua4";
```

(It's the same for me if the constant is a String or a char...)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: String myChar = "A4"; // this is probably not what you want, but I don't understand what you want.

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? have you tried \u00a4

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment why please?

Comment: @JensSchauder no, I didnt try it yet. I accepted the answer from sodium24, but thanks for also pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are encoded in UTF-16 in Java. Try this;

```
 public final static String SEPARATOR =  "\u00a4"
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `public final static String SEPARATOR = "\\ua4";`